# How do I lay out a 28 pin DIP socket pattern using GSchem?

Tags: pcb-design

How do I lay out a 28 pin DIP socket pin pattern in gSchem?

I imagine that I can lay it out manually but is there some sort of library component I can use?

VERSION: 1.6.1.20100214

Comment: I thought gschem was a *schematic* editor, not a *PCB* editor. Have things changed in the last couple of years?

Answer (score 1):

A narrow DIP-28 footprint called **DIP-28-300** exists in the pcb-symbols TGZ file.

[image: DIP-28-300 footprint]

Also, [Luciani.org](http://www.luciani.org/geda/pcb/pcb-footprint-list.html) is a good place to find footprint info, GIF files of all standard footprints, and related references.